# How to post this array and print in php?

Tags: javascript, php, json

How can I send this array back to the server so I can handle it in PHP?

```
<script>
var myJSONObject = {
        "onw": [ 
            {"name": "nilesh", "age": "31", "sal": "4000"},
            {"name1": "nitin", "age": "11", "sal": "14000"}]
};

document.write(myJSONObject.join());
</script>
```

Comment: What is the `document.write()` for? I think you'll find that `myJSONObject.join()` gives you an error given that `myJSONOBject` isn't an array. When you say "How to post?" do you mean you want to submit that data to PHP via Ajax, or...? You want to take the object (which is not JSON) and stringify it to JSON, submit the JSON, then in PHP parse it and do something with the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var json_text = JSON.stringify(myJSONObject, null, 2);

alert(json_text);

Answer (score 0):

You can use **serialization** method. i.e serialize the javascript variable and pass it to php, in php file you can **deserialize** the same.

serializing : [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: var json_text = JSON.stringify(myJSONObject, null, 2);

alert(json_text);

Answer (score 0):

Never use **document.write as its outdated**, the preferred way to add elements to DOM is using appendChild

Example Code for **appending**:

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode("some text"); // creates new text node

    textNode.appendChild(document.body); // adds to the end of the body
```

For **posting data** to php by using jquery:

Before sending it to server, you need to format it as String using **JSON.stringify**

> var formattedData = JSON.stringify(myJSONObject )
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   type: "POST",
>   url: "server.php",
>   data: formattedData ,
>   dataType: 'json',
>   success: function () {
>      alert("Data posted to php and processed succesfully"); 
>   }
> });
> ```